# Cloning a character in Dark Souls 2

Tags: dark-souls-2

How can I clone a character in Dark Souls 2 (make a copy)?

I've created a character called BuffaloBill, and done a no death run of Majula, Forest of Fallen Giants, Heide's Tower of Flame, and The Gutter.

I'd like to clone the same character, so I can use one to continue as a dex build and the other as a scorcher build.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to clone a character within the game.

The character data are all saved locally, so one option is to use a 3rd party program to edit the character data file.

Comment: Do be aware that editing save files could result in a ban.

Comment: From Software actually cannot detect your save file from being edited.  Rampant cheating was present when the game was popular.

Comment: What makes you think that? There's plenty of records of people getting banned because of invalid hacked items, edited soul memory, impossible stats, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot clone your character in game, but you can copy entire save file.

It's usually located in `%appdata%/DarkSoulsII/<steam_id>/`.

Copy entire file, then progress on character as you wish. When you want to switch to your other build, you'll have to quit game and replace save file with your backup.

Save manipulations can result in ban, but I think you are safe until you actually modify data inside save files.